# How to controll 'Choose a way to pay' in paypal using REST API

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I have integrated Paypal transaction for my shopping cart using **REST API**. When i go to the checkout, in sandbox, for some items it will display two payment methods as

> - Pay with my PayPal account.
> - Create a PayPal account.

And for some items it will display two payment methods as

> - Pay with my PayPal account.
> - Don't have a PayPal account?.

The currency is **EUR**.

always I want to display,

> - Pay with my PayPal account.
> - Don't have a PayPal account?.

this two options.

how can I do this?

Comment: Short answer: you can't control exactly what PayPal puts in these pages. They are constantly evolving them via A/B testing to improve conversion (completion) rates, and they also vary (in consistent ways) depending upon buyer characteristics (e.g. if a buyer is an experienced, "cookied" PayPal user the login path is more featured; if they buyer's computer is in a country where they must create an account in order to make payments, then "guest" payments may be disabled, etc.). Again, this is for your benefit in getting better conversion.

Comment: Yes agree with geewiz.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal not only using paypal account for transaction. We can use both debit and credit card transaction. So the customer don't need to create a paypal account. Please visit a transaction page of paypal https://www.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_flow&SESSION=Wjp0bvX7uO1uPsTRlAuXaIP7uup1VQsTi_CoeDIqrFcDhXsYfGA8V4INxJa&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b08198acc59b45c1b5383c3fbf91319c9514c0